# What's the most efficient way to partition and access dataframe rows in R?

Tags: r

I need to iterate through a dataframe, `df`, where

```
colnames(df) == c('year','month','a','id','dollars')
```

I need to iterate through all of the unique pairs `('a','id')`, which I've found via

```
counts <- count(df, c('area','normalid'))
uniquePairs <- counts[ counts$freq > 10, c('a','id') ]
```

Next I iterate through each of the unique pairs, finding the corresponding rows like so (I have named each column of `uniquePairs` appropriately):

```
aVec <- as.vector( uniquePairs$a )
idVec <- as.vector( uniquePairs$id )
for (i in 1:length(uniquePairs))
{
    a <- aVec[i]
    id <- idVec[i]

    selectRows <- (df$a==a & df$id==id)
    # ... get those rows and do stuff with them ...
    df <- df[!selectRows,] # so lookups are slightly faster next time through
    # ...
}
```

I know for loops are discouraged in general, but in this case I think it's appropriate. It at least seems to me to be irrelevant to this question, but maybe a more efficient way of doing this would get rid of the loop.

There are between 10-100k rows in the dataframe, and it makes sense that it'd be a worse-than-linear (though I haven't tested it) relationship between lookup time and `nrow(df)`.

Now `unique` must have seen where each of these pairs occurred, even if it didn't save it. Is there a way to save that off, so that I have a boolean vector I could use for each of the pairs to more efficiently select them out of the dataframe? Or is there an alternate, better way to do this?

I have a feeling that some use of `plyr` or `reshape` could help me out, but I'm still relatively new to the large R ecosystem, so some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` is your best option by far:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,{do stuff in here, then leave results in list form},by=list(a, id)]
```

for a simple case of an average of some variable:

```
dt[,list(Mean = mean(dollars)), by = list(a, id)]
```

Comment: I have more than one row of output for every unique `(a,id)`. For a simple example, how could I do something like this: `dt[,list(Mean=rep(3,mean(dollars)),by=list(a,id)]` using `data.table`?

Comment: If `Mean` is of length 3, `data.table` will automatically create three rows for that particular combination of `a` and `id`.